# c# overplus name space increase load on page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

dose unused namespace on the c# asp.net web forms or win form application increase application load ?  i remove that unused when implementing completed

[image: sample like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**, it does not increase "application load"

From [The C# Team's answers to frequently asked questions:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx)

> When you add assembly references or make use of the 'using' keyword,
>   csc.exe will ignore any assembly which you have not actually made use
>   of in your code. Thus, if you were to set a reference to
>   System.Data.dll and System.Windows.Forms.dll but only authored the
>   following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;  // Ignored. 
using System.Windows.Forms; // Ignored. 

public class MyClass
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hi there.");
  }
}
```

> the compiler would only reference the mandatory mscorlib.dll.

Answer (score 0):

The number of namespaces used in code does not have any effect on runtime performance of the web or windows application in dot.net however it have some impact on compile time as the compiler must search those unused namespaces.